# PHP iterating through array - Can't reach top level values?

Tags: json, loops, foreach, iterator, iteration

I try to search long and hard to find my answers and almost never ask questions if I can help it. but it's 5am and I've been working on this project for quite a few months now and I'm stuck.

```
THE PROBLEM
```

I have a JSON file saved on my local server which has the following layout:

*Note I've cut down the JSON file to remove the bloat and focus on exactly what I'm trying to extract here.

```
{
"count": 74,
"results": [
    {
        "listing_id": 151323205,
          "Images": [
            {
                "url_75x75": "https:\/\/img1.etsystatic.com\/013\/0\/7566894\/il_75x75.459599049_hptl.jpg",
            },

        ]
    }
],
"params": {
    "limit": "1",
    "shop_id": "username",
},
```

}

```
THE CODE
```

Now I've managed to iterate through all the other stuff like 'listing_id' & 'Images' but it appears the 'shop_id' is outside of the scope of my foreach command and inside the 'params' portion?

```
            foreach($results->results as $product){

                    $products[$i]['url_75x75']      = $product->Images[0]->url_75x75;

                $i++;
            }
```

I'm not super PHP savvy so If you can dumb it down just a bit? It's probably something very simple for you guys and I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong and how to do it right.

This isn't the full code like I stated so if you need more insight please ask. I didn't want to bombard people with  a bunch of my keyboard slapping coding skills :)

Thank you so much! I love SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the shop id with the following code:

```
$shop_id = $results->params->shop_id;
```

You can use this inside the foreach loop if you want to (though its value will not change of course).

Comment: Whoa, I could have sworn I tried that, hmm.

Anyway! It worked flawlessly, thank you very much! I'll set this to answered A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

`$results` is probably your whole object, which contains all the data that was in the JSON. `$results->results` reads only the "results" part inside the JSON, so the loop only iterates over what is in there.

To read the shop id, you can just read:

```
echo $results->params->shop_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Params is on the same level as results so in your for each where you are looking at $results->results, you are not including params, you can nest your for each like

```
Foreach ($results as $result) {
    Foreach ($result->results){}
    Foreach ($result->params){}
}
```